# 9000 Files moved to local Google Drive folder, ca. 500 files missing afterwards

Tags: google-drive

Being a new fan of the cloud, I moved all my important folders and files (ca. 18 GB) to the Google Drive folder on my Windows 10 PC. I have the 100 GB package.

The sync started in the background and I let it running (on a slow connection).

Just today I found out that about 500 files are missing! They are not existing locally anymore, and also not on the Drive. Obviously, Google Drive removed them from my local Google Drive folder instead of uploading them to the cloud.

Now I am wondering:

1. How is that possible? Sync issue?
2. How can I recover the files? They are definitely gone. Also not in the trash bins (online/offline). (Lucky me I have a backup from a month ago, but just imagine another user without backup faces the same problem.)
3. How to prevent the nirvana-loss of files?

Thanks for any advice and help.

Comment: Is it the only you who allowed to connect to GD? Are there any other devices setup to sync with GD?

Comment: My Android smartphone has also access. However, the Google Drive app was not running.

Comment: Did you check trash bin online and in recycle bin locally, are there missing files?

Comment: Checked all. The missing files are not there. That's the evil part of the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I attempted to move my photos folder over to the drive. It seems when you drop a very large amount of files or folders over at once it just stalls and never actually syncronises them.

This is possibly a thread worth following:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/qGVqIqEllJg

If I get to the bottom of it before you I'll post it here.

Cheers

Phill

Comment: I think it's not the same issue, as in the forum it's "preparing to sync", and here, it's a sync that has be done, but wasn't reliable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, of course, it's possible, it happens often with sync, or if you copy a move a really long list of files.
2. Recover your file with a recovery software. Stop using your drive right now, and start the recovery, because each thing you save on your disk will have a risk to be saved in the same place than your previous data. It's a very long process, as it needs to scan your hard disk in totality.

[https://www.techradar.com/news/the-best-free-file-recovery-software](http://Here%20is%20a%20list) of free recovery softwares, but you can opt for paying ones.

The free ones, are for instance: EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard Free

Google it, and you will find tons of them.

3. How to prevent the loss of files:

Never trust one software (and I won't trust Google sync!)

So, the good and safe way to make a sync is to make first a one way sync (copying files), to compare the 2 drives, and then to automatically delete the files locally if the drives have the same content.

You can use CarotDAV (free & open source) or Odrive to sync your files. To make a virtual folder, looking like a local folder and simply moving the files. If you have to copy tons of files, you can use a special copy tool (fastcopy for instance).